# Append Command From One Batch to another

Tags: batch-file, copy, set, append, backup

I am trying to write a batch file that will write a new line with a "MOVE" command to a second batch file.  We have a master batch file with a MOVE command for every PC that uses a piece of our software so we can back the records up to a network drive (scheduled to run daily).  Data on the local PC's gets deleted after 20 days and we need to create a place to hold these files permanently.  Unfortunately this is the best way to keep our data backed up, I'm just trying to automate the process to make the process as easy as I can for my department.  I'm trying the command below but I think it's an issue with the quotation marks.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
    :START 

    ECHO.
    SET /p pcid=Please enter the PCID that you would like to setup for Auto-Archiving:
        IF "%pcid%"=="%%" (GOTO CONFIRMPC)
        IF "%pcid%"=="exit" (GOTO END)

    :CONFIRMPC

    ECHO.
    ECHO Please verify that "%pcid%" is correct...
    ECHO.
    SET /p verify=Enter y/n...
        IF "%verify%"=="y" (GOTO SETUPAUTOARC)
        IF "%verify%"=="n" (GOTO START)
        IF "%verify%"=="%%" (GOTO VERIFYERROR)
        IF "%verify%"=="exit" (GOTO END)

    :VERIFYERROR

    ECHO.
    ECHO Please enter a valid (y/n) response...
    (GOTO CONFIRMPC)

    :SETUPAUTOARC

    ECHO.
    ECHO Creating directory...
    MKDIR "\\server32\e$\Backup Data\%pcid%"
    ECHO.
(HERE IS WHERE I'M RUNNING INTO TROUBLE)
    ECHO "MOVE "\\%pcid%\C$\Program Files\Application\Data\*.xml" > "\\server32\c$\scripts\masterbackup.bat
    ECHO.
    SET /p endresp=Finished! Would you like to run another PCID? (y/n)
        IF "%endresp%"=="y" (GOTO START)
        IF "%endresp%"=="n" (GOTO END)

    :END

    exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ECHO "MOVE "\\%pcid%\C$\Program Files\Application\Data\*.xml" > "\\server32\c$\scripts\masterbackup.bat
---- ^ Remove this quote and add an extra waaaaay up at the very end...................................^.here
```

The syntax is `ECHO string > file`

Where quotes should be balanced and need to be placed around any (full-)filename that contains spaces (etc.)

Note also that `>` will write the data to a **NEW** file, deleting the exiting (if any). Use `>>` to **APPEND** to an existing file.

---

Having said that, all the command would do is put or add a line

```
MOVE "\\%pcid%\C$\Program Files\Application\Data\*.xml"
```

to the file `"\\server32\c$\scripts\masterbackup.bat"`

That doesn't seem to be particularly rational. Shouldn't you be `MOVE`ing the fileset to somewhere and appending *that* `move` command to the batch?

Comment: I just want to append that new line to the existing batch so when the it runs there will be a MOVE command for the PC just added.  I need that PC to be in the existing batch file b/c that file runs daily.

Comment: So use `>>` not `>`. I can't advise precisely what your `move` command should be. The PCID should be substituted in the line from the variable `pcid`, but I've no idea what your proposed destination should be.

Comment: Yep, I replaced the > with >> and edited the quotation marks and that worked perfect.  Thank you so much!